# You say tomato, I say tomato, you say Ultima Thule, I say 2014-MU69. How to deal with dual names and tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I created [2014-mu69](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2014-mu69) a year and a half ago but they've since nick-named the asteroid Ultima Thule and people use that a lot.

It currently has 8 questions and no doubt in the next week it will get more, since the New Horizons flyby is imminent.

Is there a simple way to make it so when people start typing "ulti..." or "thul..." that they see the correct tag appear in the options?

Comment: Not an asteroid, I think.

Comment: @OscarLanzi [Do astronomers generally agree that the distinction between comets and astroids is not so clear?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19963/7982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, it's called tag synonyms. Add in your suggestion, and it can be confirmed and then that is the behavior.

Comment: Ah, I had thought tag synonyms happened only after two tags merged with some minimum number of uses on each tag. This sounds much easier than that. Thanks!

Comment: `2014-mu69` has eight questions https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVXS9.png but I got this message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ5VF.png That means I need to add the new tag to five questions before they can be merged?